# How to get from Haneda airport to Narita airport?

Tags: public-transport, japan, tokyo, nrt, hnd

I have an Air Asia flight to Haneda, Tokyo's smaller airport. I then need to get to Narita. What public transport options do I have?

(Assume during the day, as I'll likely nap in the airport until services start running in the morning).

Comment: Actually, Haneda is much bigger than Narita (4th in the world, while Narita is 38th). ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_busiest_airports_by_passenger_traffic#2013_statistics

Comment: Haneda has far fewer international flights though, although with the recent expansions they're now increasing rapidly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can take the [airport shuttle](https://www.limousinebus.co.jp/en/time_searches/index.html) (Airport Limousine Bus) direct from Haneda (International Terminal) to Narita (Terminal 1 then Terminal 2) for 3,100 JPY. It comes fairly regularly (roughly hourly) and takes around 95 minutes. The earliest departure is 06:25.

Alternatively you can take the train. The best route depends on time of arrival, but your main options will be:

**Route A**

- Haneda -> Shinagawa (Keikyu Main/Airport Line Rapid Ltd. Exp., 13 mins)
- Shinagawa -> Narita (Narita Express, 68 mins)

Total route cost: 3,600 JPY.

**Route B**

- Haneda (through Sengakuji, Oshiage and Aoto) -> Narita (it's one physical line but changes name across the journey, starting out as the Keikyu Main/Airport Line and changing to Toei Asakusa Line, then Keisei Oshiage Line and finally Keisei Narita Sky Access, 94 minutes)

Total route cost: 1,760 JPY

If you want specific timings to plan your train journey and see which of the routes is better for you, check out the always-useful [Hyperdia](http://www.hyperdia.com/en/) website.

Having taken the bus I strongly recommend it - very comfortable, spacious and air-conditioned. What's more, you can see some incredible urban views on the elevated express ways and drops you right at departures at Narita.

Comment: The bus is by far the best option for this, especially if you've got bags. However, there are occasional direct trains from Haneda to Narita; cheaper than the bus, and no transfers needed, but slower and less comfortable.

Comment: Agreed. That's the 'Route B' I mention - no changes and direct.

Comment: Note that if you are connecting to a flight (which is still very normal) on the same ticket that leaves from the other airport your airline will go to a reasonable effort to inform you of how to catch the bus and the flight times will be generally coordinated with the bus time.

Comment: @codinghands my edit was to fix/update the link to the bus service site, referenced in answered a similar question (not dupe).