# From Haneda airport to Narita airport with same airline

Tags: airport-transfer, short-connections, nrt, hnd

We will arrive in Haneda airport at 7:10am and connecting flight to US from Narita is 11:15am.

Is there enough time to catch my next flight?

I've confirmed with UA that we don't need to pick up our luggage during the connecting flight but we have to go through Immigration, that usually may take an hour.

What's the best way not to miss our next flight?

Is there a fast lane for Immigration and direct transportation from one airport to the other?

What if I miss the flight, will UA give us the next availability flight without penalty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get from Haneda airport to Narita airport?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30779/how-to-get-from-haneda-airport-to-narita-airport)

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate as the OP here is asking about transfer times. However the information contained in the linked question does provide insights to answer the OP's question.

Comment: Is your flight to Haneda also international?  What carrier are you flying with, and is it on a single ticket?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, if you've been sold the entire itinerary as a single ticket, it's by definition a valid connection, and UA will put you on the next flight for free if you don't make it for a sensible reason (incoming flight delayed, etc).  So don't worry too much.

That said, it's going to be **a bit tighter than I'd recommend**.  Four hours would be more than sufficient for a domestic HND/int'l NRT connection (the minimum connecting time for this is [usually around three hours](http://www.ana.co.jp/wws/japan/e/local/dom/checkin/information/procedures.html)), but I take it you're flying internationally into Haneda as well, which means you will need to go through immigration at both ends.

The [Limousine Bus](https://www.limousinebus.co.jp/en/bus_services/narita/haneda.html) is the easiest way to connect between the two airports, but you would need a dab of luck to get through immigration in time to catch the 07:40 service. If you can't, the next is at 08:25, arriving 10 AM, leaving you with only a bit over an hour to get through security and immigration — still doable, especially if you're already checked in and don't need to worry about bags, but tight.

You could also take the trains, but this requires a transfer at Shinagawa, costs more and is generally more hassle.  However, since you don't have luggage, it shouldn't be too bad.  [Google Maps](https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir/Haneda+Airport+International+Terminal+Station,+Haneda,+Tokyo,+Japan/Narita+International+Airport,+1-1+Furugome,+Narita,+Chiba+Prefecture+282-0004,+Japan/@35.6752478,139.9106481,11z/data=!4m18!4m17!1m5!1m1!1s0x60186156b2f277b1:0xc59dac631427bf6c!2m2!1d139.767021!2d35.54506!1m5!1m1!1s0x6022f379d1bd3757:0xd56e29a162771aa1!2m2!1d140.39285!2d35.771987!2m2!7e2!8j1422604800!3e3!5i3) outlines some options from 8 AM on a random Friday (adjust dates at will).

I don't suppose you have to option to change to a HND/HND or NRT/NRT connection?  It would be *much* easier, and YMMV, I'd pay a few hundred bucks extra for the privilege.

Comment: The day of the week will greatly impact how long it takes. If it's a weekday and you are fighting with rush hour, trains are far far far less appealing. It also depends on if you have status/where you're sitting on the incoming flight as you may be able to get out of immigration far faster.