# Travelling to USA with a four hour layover between Narita and Haneda

Tags: visas, transit, filipino-citizens, nrt, hnd

I'm a Philippine passport holder travelling to USA via Narita and, four hours later, Haneda.

Do I need a transit visa?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need a visa, as you'll be entering the country. The Philippines are [not among the visa exempt countries for visiting Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Japan#Visa_exempt_countries), and the Japan embassy in the Philippines [has a list of all relevant documents / info that you may need](http://www.ph.emb-japan.go.jp/visiting/).

Narita and Haneda are [almost 50 miles apart](http://www.webjet.com/travel/airport-transfers-tokyo/), so you definitely have to exit the airport to get to the other.

We have a question on [getting between the two airports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30779/how-to-get-from-haneda-airport-to-narita-airport).