# Is 4h 15m enough time to transit Haneda airport to Narita airport?

Tags: airport-transfer, short-connections, nrt, hnd

When I come back from Vietnam to North America, I have an airplane transfer in Japan. The arrival time is 6:55 AM in Haneda airport and my second plane is set at 11:10 AM the same morning... (gives me a small total of 4 hours and 15 minutes to get from the first one to the second one).

I read that it takes about 90 minutes with the airport bus system, but that it could take much longer because of traffic (and that I could wait some time before the bus departs).

It is possible? What is my alternative if this doesn't seem doable? Call my flight agency and change it?

Comment: What airlines are you flying with?

Comment: See also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30779/how-to-get-from-haneda-airport-to-narita-airport

Comment: If you are worried about traffic, you can take trains, but there is no direct train betwee 7 and 9am so you will need to make some transfers.

Comment: Trains will be quite crowded at rush hour.  The limousine bus is your best bet, and it should be OK since nearly all the trip is outward from Tokyo (rush hour traffic is in the other direction).

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with trains, you can make the trip in 90-120 minutes, depending on your time of departure. This comes down to whether you check or carry-on, your facility in navigating the airport/rail station, and your tolerance for OJ Simpson-like sprints to the departure gates. Personally, I'd plan more time between flights. Here is a link for checking train schedules. http://www.hyperdia.com/
Easy to use and all in English.