# What is the time of last trip of bus from Haneda airport to Narita airport 2 during the night?

Tags: japan, nrt, hnd

I'll be arriving on Dec. 24, 2018 at 9:30 PM at the Haneda International airport. I would like to know the last trip of bus from Haneda to Narita airport.

Comment: I think this is technically be off-topic, but the four up-votes appear to disagree. "asking to have your travel itinerary constructed, including flight scheduling, budgeting and finding accommodation. Such questions cannot be answered as there are too many variables and personal preferences to account for, and are unlikely to be of use to others. An actual travel agent may be of assistance." How stable is that bus schedule, and how permanent is this question?

Comment: @Steve It's on topic and a perfectly valid question with permanent relevance.  Schedules may indeed change, but bus operators and their websites not so much.

Answer (score 11):

The [airport shuttle bus](https://www.limousinebus.co.jp/en/areas/detail/nrt/haneda/for) runs 24-hours-a-day, with departures about every 20 minutes during much of the day to hourly from midnight to early morning. Travel time is about 90 to 100 minutes, depending on the terminal of departure at Haneda and arrival at Narita. The fare is ￥3,100 ($27 USD).

Another option is the train, as explained by @codinghands in response to an earlier question on [How to get from Haneda airport to Narita airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30779/how-to-get-from-haneda-airport-to-narita-airport).

Comment: +1, but unlike the buses, the trains *do* stop running at night.